# JSHint error Don't make functions within a loop

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm running some code through JSHint and I keep getting the following error:

> Don't make functions within a loop.

I tried turning off the warning for 'About functions inside loops' off which does nothing to stop the error from being reported. I have decided to refactor the code, using JSHint's suggestions here, http://www.jshint.com/options/ but I'm still getting the error. I was hoping that somebody could help me to refactor this code slightly so it will pass. Here's a copy of the function:

```
function setSounds(parent) {
    var i,
        l;

    parent.getElements('.sound').each(function (elem) {
        var soundEvents = [];

        if (elem.get('fk_click_sound')) {
            soundEvents.push('click');
        }

        if (elem.get('fk_mouseover_sound')) {
            soundEvents.push('mouseenter');
        }

        if (soundEvents.length !== 0) {
            for (i = 0, l = soundEvents.length; i < l; i += 1) {
                elem.addEvent(soundEvents[i], (function () {
                    return function (e) {
                        FKSoundAIR(FKSoundStd[this.get('fk_' + e.type + '_sound')]);
                    };
                })(elem), false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using MooTools. The purpose of this function is to pass a parent element and then apply sound event to all of the children with the class 'sound.' I'm using custom HTML attributes, such as 'fk_click_sound' to feed additional information to the function.  I picked up this method of assigning a function within a loop from http://blog.jbrantly.com/2010/04/creating-javascript-function-inside.html.

Any suggestions or resources that you can point me to would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that it's an error? It could just be a warning.

Comment: It is just a warning but its popping up in my ant build process which causes the build to stop from completing.

Comment: @Spencer: Could you revert your edit at the top, submit your solution as an answer, and then accept your own answer to close out this question?  That will remove this from the list of unanswered questions.  Cheers!

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I moved the edit into a separate answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function make_handler(div_id) {
    return function () {
        alert(div_id);
    }
}
for (i ...) {
    div_id = divs[i].id;
    divs[i].onclick = make_handler(div_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the function outside, assign it to a `var` and use it in your call to `addEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out JS Hint had a bug re: the warning for Looping inside of a function, which they fixed [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/278).  Now that this is fixed, this issue is resolved.

Comment: The issue isn't resolved: try pasting the text from the question into jshint.com.  I believe your link was about something else.